# Extrêmement lumineuses [...] ou même moins

Tags: style-de-rédaction, ambiguïté

Sur Wikipédia, à propos des [étoiles géantes bleues](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A9ante_bleue) :

> Les géantes bleues sont extrêmement lumineuses, de magnitude absolue -5, -6 ou **même moins**.

La tournure semble un peu maladroite. Cette impression provient probablement de la rencontre de plusieurs cas particuliers qui se rencontrent ici :

- *« extrêmement lumineuses »*, version superlative, outrée de la luminosité, une caractéristique que je déclarerai ici *positive* en ce sens qu’une augmentation en accentue la perception par nos sens ou nos instruments, et en accroît sa proportion par rapport à l’ensemble du milieu (selon cette classification, *« grandeur »* ou *« densité »* seraient de même des caractéristiques *positives*, alors que *« petitesse »* ou *« ténuité »* seraient des caractéristiques *négatives*, une augmentation de ces dernières faisant tendre la perceptibilité vers le néant).
- [MAGNITUDE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/magnitude) : Importance (d’une donnée, d’un fait). De nouveau une caratéristique *positive*. Le terme a été choisi en remplacement de *grandeur* pour la luminosité par Norman Robert Pogson au milieu du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle. Depuis de nombreux siècles, on utilisait une classification des étoiles en fonction de leur luminosité en déclarant les plus brillantes comme étant *« de première grandeur »*, celles un peu moins brillantes *« de deuxième grandeur »*, et ainsi de suite par luminosité apparente décroissante jusqu’à la sixième grandeur, aux confins de la perception occulaire humaine. Voici l’historique à ce sujet, présenté sur Wikipédia :

  > Le premier classement des étoiles en fonction de leur brillance remonte à l'Antiquité[. A]u II<sup>e</sup> siècle av. J.-C. l'astronome grec Hipparque aurait<sup>1</sup> réalisé un catalogue d'un millier d'étoiles visibles à l'œil nu. L'échelle comprend alors six *« grandeurs »* : les étoiles les plus brillantes sont de première grandeur et les étoiles les moins brillantes encore visibles à l'œil nu sont de sixième grandeur. Cette méthode de classement a été ensuite popularisée dans Almageste de Ptolémée au II<sup>e</sup> siècle [de notre ère].
  >   <sub><sup>1</sup> On notera que les écrits d’Hipparque n’existent plus, et qu’on les connaît aujourd’hui par leur utilisation citée de Ptolémée, d’où vraisemblablement l’utilisation du conditionnel ici.</sub>
- Dans le but de conserver les valeurs de cette classification, ce même Pogson élabore une échelle logarithmique inverse, qui diminuera la valeur de la *magnitude* à mesure que l’objet considéré est plus brillant. Des magnitudes négatives sont ainsi créées pour les objets particulièrement brillants, la magnitude<sup>2</sup> de l’étoile Sirius, de 1, devient -1 selon cette nouvelle échelle. Vénus atteindra -5 à son maximum de luminosité. La pleine lune près de -13 et le soleil -26,7. Nous avons donc ici une caractéristique que la langue naturelle veut positive, mais que la science a rendu *« négative »*, par une échelle inversée construite pour mimiquer une classification *classique*.

  <sub><sup>2</sup> Les magnitudes indiquées en exemples sont des magnitudes apparentes, qui utilisent la même échelle que la magnitude absolue, mais diffèrent de celle-ci en ce sens qu’elles sont mesurées du point de vue de la Terre, alors que les magnitudes absolues sont déterminées par la luminosité qu’aurait un objet observé à une distance fixe, arbitrairement fixée à 10 parsecs (32,6 années-lumière).</sub>

Pour discuter de la possibilité d’une plus grande luminosité *(première partie de la phrase)*, on doit donc invoquer une diminution de la magnitude *(seconde partie)*. Ce genre d’ambiguïté linguistique n’est pas sans rappeler la savante impertinence de Courteline sur le genre ambivalent de certains mots français :

> Les mots *amour*, *délice* et *orgue* étant masculins au singulier et féminins au pluriel, on doit dire, en bonne logique : *« Cet orgue est le plus beau des plus belles »*, si on ne veut encourir le reproche d’écrire sa langue comme un cochon.

---

- Le tour n’est peut-être pas idéal. Pourrait-on trouver des exemples équivalents, similairement *« étranges »* dans la littérature publiée ? Seraient-elle, le cas échéant, plutôt volontairement grotesque (plutôt confinée à des écrits humoristiques ou lyriques), ou la trouverait-on aussi dans des écrits plus neutres ?
- Y aurait-il d’autres possibilités qui puissent transmettre la même information sans que le lecteur « accroche » ?
- Que penserait-on de cette version légèrement modifiée de l’originale ? Même conclusion ?

  > Les géantes bleues sont extrêmement lumineuses, leur magnitude absolue atteignant typiquement -5 ou -6, alors que celle du soleil **n’est que de** +4.8.

Comment: Pour moi la tournure est correcte est pas spécialement maladroite. *ou même moins* s'applique à *-5 ou -6*, pas directement à la luminosité. La confusion vient surtout des termes techniques, un peu contre-intuitifs (magnitude qui peut être négative, magnitude absolue qui n'est pas une valeur absolue (qui serait forcément positive), ...).

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Merci de votre commentaire. Maintenant, si des exemples similaires de publications reconnues pouvaient illustrer que le tour est parfaitement usité et pas du tout controversé, ça répondrait parfaitement à la question.

Comment: Ca ne me chope pas non plus.

Comment: rem: les magnitudes indiquées pour le soleil, la lune et venus sont ici des magnitudes apparentes (qui dépend de leur distance à la terre). Leurs magnitudes absolues (mesurées à 10 parsec) seraient bien plus élevées que celles des géantes bleues.

Answer (score 4):

Il n'y a rien de choquant si on lit cette phrase à voix haute "...moins 5, moins 6 et même moins". C'est également logique, vu que la luminosité décroit avec la magnitude (qu'elle soit apparente ou absolue). On peut par contre reprocher le choix du terme "magnitude absolue" pour une grandeur négative, (d'autant plus que la valeur absolue d'un nombre est positive, mais "absolu" est, ici, utilisé par opposition à "relatif" ou "apparent", et non dans son sens "mathématique"). Ceci étant dit, le choix d'un terme par les scientifiques n'enlève rien à la tournure que vous citez. Il serait toutefois possible de contourner le problème en utilisant les unité solaires de luminosité au lieu des magnitudes absolues, mais cela ne serait (à mon humble avis) pas nécessairement plus "beau":

> Les géantes bleues sont extrêmement lumineuses, 20000 à 50000 fois plus que le soleil, ou même encore plus.

Comme autre exemple, on peut regarder du côté de la chimie:

> Ces acides sont extrêmement forts, avec des pKa de -4, -6 et même moins. L'acide le plus fort a un pKa de -25 alors que le pKa de
>   l'acide sulfurique est de 1.99.

EDIT: Plus connu que le pKa, le pH est utilisé pour mesurer l'acidité d'une solution aqueuse. C'est aussi une grandeur basée sur l'opposé d'un logarithme (et pas le logarithme), qui diminue donc lorsque la concentration en ions H<sub>3</sub>O<sup>+</sup> augmente (donc plus la solution est acide, plus le pH est faible). Je pense qu'on a pris l'opposé du logarithme pour avoir des valeurs positives et pas une échelle négative. L'origine n'est donc pas la compatibilité avec un classement ordinal comme c'est le cas avec la luminosité des étoiles (où, bizarrement, l'échelle négative a été favorisée). Par ailleurs, on peut tout aussi bien considérer le pH comme une mesure de basicité, et dans ce cas on a bien une combinaison croissant/croissant. Dans le même ordre d'idée, l'antonyme de luminosité est l'obscurité, mais parler d'une étoile "peu obscure" aurait tout de la litote.

EDIT 2 : Dans un tout autre contexte, la logique "moins c'est mieux" s'applique aussi à la plupart des compétitions sportives de vitesse. On y parle de vitesse, mais la grandeur utilisée est en fait bien souvent le temps (inversement proportionnel à la vitesse). Au golf, le but est également de faire un minimum de coups.

> Ce coureur est extrêmement rapide, il court le 100 m en 9.7 secondes,
>   et même parfois moins.

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour votre réponse et pour les ajouts successifs que vous y apportez. J'aime beaucoup le contraste entre la mienne, qui cherche à justifier l'ambiguïté, et la vôtre, qui veut démontrer que le cas de la question n'est pas unique et parfaitement normal dans bien des cas. Deux recherches dans deux directions distinctes, qui se complètent et qui ensemble offrent un panorama intéressant.

Answer (score 3):

À la lumière des premiers commentaires et de la première réponse, on peut sentir une certaine perplexité des gens devant ma question : rien ne semble clocher ici selon les intervenants.

Il apparaît donc que ne causerait point d’ambiguïté notable ou de sentiment de maladresse grammaticale la valeur inversée de la mesure astronomique de la magnitude d’un objet céleste (qui décroît à mesure que celui-ci est plus brillant) par rapport à l’acception linguistique habituelle du terme (qui croît avec la grandeur mesurée).

On trouve en littéraire des exemples de l’usage habituel, pour lesquels la magnitude, bien que non-chiffrée, indique une grandeur incontestable. Côté sciences, on trouve aussi une autre échelle de magnitude, croissante celle-ci, et donc plus conforme à l’accpetion commune habituelle : l’échelle de Richter, qui est une mesure de l’énergie libérée par un séisme. Et enfin, la magnitude des objets de l’étude astronomique, celle même de la question, fut parfois indiquée comme « synonyme de grandeur astrale », ce qui entraînera quelques conséquences mineures qui seront exposées plus loin.

En littérature et autres sujets non-chiffrés d’abord :

> Les Utopiens recordantz en quel danger iceulx dons admonnestent les hommes de se metre, metent peine que la grandeur du peril soit recompensée, par **magnitude** & abondance de biens, pourtant prometent ils non seulement gros mouceau d’or, ains terres & lieux de grãd revenu, en endroictz seurs chez leurs amyz, lesquelz ils assignent comme leur propre & a jamais, a ceulx qui font telz actes, & leur tiennent promesse fidelement & entiere.
>               <sup>—*La description de l’isle d’Utopie, ou est comprins le miroer des républicques du monde, & l’exemplaire de vie heureuse (1515)*, (Saint) Thomas More, traduit par Jean Leblond et publié en français en 1550</sup>
>     Je débouche la bouteille de Vat 69 — les seules boutanches dont on ne reconnaisse pas le cul du goulot — et toute affaire cessante m’en transfuse un gorgeon **de première magnitude**
>               <sup>—*Nous avons les moyens de vous faire parler (1975)*, Patrice Dard</sup>
>   Pour n’avoir rien de comparable comme magnificence, comme **magnitude**, comme capacité aux théâtres de Rome qui étaient immenses, et à ceux de quelques-unes des villes principales de l’Italie et du monde romain, le théâtre de la vallée de la Vonne n’était point ce qu’on pourrait appeler un petit théâtre.
>               <sup>—*Monuments gallo-romains de la vallée de la Vonne (Vienne)*, 1884</sup>
>       À l’est, les deux pics ardus qui précédaient la Sierra Paricis se déployaient dans toute leur **magnitude**.
>               <sup>—*Les baleiniers (1859)*, Alexandre Dumas</sup>

On notera que si l’on désirait chiffrer le second exemple, on se retrouverait exactement dans le cas de la magnitude astronomique traitée dans la question, avec les mêmes conséquences. On pourrait même substituer *classe* à *magnitude* et conserver le même effet. Je laisse au lecteur le soin de juger du bon sens d’une telle tournure :

- [...] et toute affaire cessante je m’en tranfuse un gorgeon de moins cinquième, moins sixième magnitude, voire moins.

Passons maintenant à la magnitude sismique. L’exemple suivant, bien qu’ayant pour but d’expliciter les effets de la nature *logarithmique* de l’échelle de Richter, indique néanmoins pour se faire la nature directe (et non inverse) des accroissements respectifs de la magnitudes et des effets du séisme :

> L’échelle de Richter mesure la **magnitude** : l’échelle de Mercalli, l’intensité, c’est-à-dire les effets de surface, destructeurs. L’échelle de Richter est logarithmique, c’est-à-dire qu’**un accroissement de la magnitude** dans l’échelle se traduit par **un accroissement des effets** proportionnel aux effets déjà observés. Il y a effet d’accélération.
>           <sup>—*Hérodote : stratégies, géographies, idéologies* (1982), dirigé par Yves Lacoste</sup>

Et finalement la magnitude visuelle des étoiles, qui traite directement des magnitudes des objets célestes, liant parfois magnitude et grandeur ou éclat, au prix d’une explication (parfois absente) pour définir clairement la nature numérique particulière de la magnitude d’un astre :

> L’éclat apparent d’une étoile est apprécié, aujourd’hui, par sa ***magnitude***, terme synonyme de grandeur astrale.
>           <sup>—*Revue belge*, 1931</sup>

Affirmation qui demanderait à être amendée par une longue explication, que fournira l’exemple suivant :

> **Éclat. Grandeur ou magnitude.** — L’éclat d’une étoile, qui caractérise l’impression plus ou moins intense qu’elle produit sur l’œil est défini par le flux lumineux que cette étoile envoie sur l’unité de surface, passant par l’œil de l’observateur et normale aux rayons venant de l’étoile. On peut dire aussi que c’est l’éclairement produit par la lumière de l’étoile sur la surface que l’on vient de considérer.
>
> Les astronomes ont l’habitude de caractériser l’éclat d’une étoile par une donnée, qui dérive conventionnellement de l’éclat, et qui est désignée par les mots : grandeur ou magnitude, avec cette particularité que **la magnitude diminue quand l’éclat augmente**. Par définition, les magnitudes croissent en progression arithmétique quand les éclats décroissent en progression géométrique, et, par convention, entre deux étoiles dont les éclats sont entre eux dans le rapport de 100 à 1 il y a me différence de 5 magnitudes.
>           <sup>—*Bureau des longitudes*, 1974</sup>

---

#### D’une classification ordinale à un continuum

Les anciens, en compartimentant les étoiles en des classes de valeurs entières dont la première est la plus importante, suivaient un raisonnement dont on retrouve de nombreux exemples dans la langue :

- la première classe dans le transport ferroviaire ou aérien ;
- le premier ministre ;
- de premier choix ;
- premier de classe ;

On pourrait voir l’une des inspirations de ces figures dans l’idée que la première étape d’un projet, d’une recette, etc. est celle à laquelle on doit s’attaquer de *prime abord*, avant de pouvoir passer aux suivantes.

Nous avons aussi, étymologiquement, [*priorité*](http://cnrtl.fr/etymologie/priorit%C3%A9) qui nous viendrait de *primauté de rang*.

On notera aussi le soin de corriger la perception désavantageuse généralement accordée à ceux qui suivent le premier dans l’expression courante :

- Le (second / troisième / quatrième / dernier) mais **non le moindre**.

<sub>Je note aussi en passant l’exemple des brûlures, où celles du premier degré sont les moins graves, et qui suit donc une logique inverse. La langue n’est pas un phénomène monolithique, et elle procède de différentes manières, ce qui donne parfois des résultats qui peuvent sembler antithétiques.</sub>

Passer d’une classification discrète (utilisant des nombres entiers) ordinale et bornée à un continuum ouvert aux deux bouts, comme on le fit pour la magnitude en astronomie, est un processus risqué qui ne s’accomplit pas nécessairement sans soubresauts. Quand la valeur d’une *grandeur* (habituellement, on pourra déclarer *grandeur* et *magnitude* synonymes, ce que je sous-entends explicitement ici) se met à diminuer à mesure qu’augmente ladite grandeur, on peut se retrouver dans une situation linguistique paradoxale, à un synonyme près de quelque chose comme :

- À mesure qu’augmente la magnitude de l’éclat d’une étoile, sa magnitude diminue.

---

#### Un exemple apparenté à celui de la question

On a cité dans [la première réponse soumise](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/34511/13100) un exemple avec le pKa d’un acide, qui diminue à mesure qu’augmente la force de l’acide, et dont la valeur est négative pour les acides très forts.

> Ces acides sont extrêmement forts, avec des pK<sub>a</sub> de -4, -6 **et même moins**. L'acide le plus fort a un pK<sub>a</sub> de -25 alors que le pK<sub>a</sub> de l'acide sulfurique est de 1,99.

Il semble bien ici que ce soit un exemple typique de ce qui est critiqué dans la question, et en ce il semble très approprié de le citer. Je note malgré tout deux très légères différences :

- Le pK<sub>a</sub> n’est pas un mot de la langue courante attribué plus tard à une grandeur scientifique. S’il est possible au néophyte de se méprendre quant à la nature numérique de l’échelle citée, il ne le fera jamais en extrapolant de sa connaissance linguistique du terme. Cette possibilité n’est pas exclue quand un terme comme *magnitude* est utilisé (quoique les deux exemples proposés laissent peu de place à la mésinterprétation, d’autres exemples plus ambigus sont possibles).
- On n’est pas passé d’une échelle ordinale à un continuum en créant la mesure du pK<sub>a</sub>. Le concept a été créé au XX<sup>e</sup> siècle à partir de mesures précises et contrôlées, et l’échelle fut d’emblée étalonnée en fonction des données numériques obtenues, au contraire de la classification moins rigoureuse héritée de l’Antiquité pour les magnitudes stellaires.

---

#### Les classements sportifs

Supposons que l’on cherche à prédire le classement futur d’un jeune athlète prometteur commençant à faire sa marque dans un sport. Je pourrais concevoir quelque chose comme :

- Il se hissera certainement dans le top 20 d’ici l’an prochain, et très vraisemblablement au-delà dans les prochaines années.

Mais en dépit qu’au-delà du top 20 se trouvent les positions *moindres* numériquement, une affirmation comme la suivante me semble inconcevable :

- Elle progressera sans nul doute jusqu’au top 20 avant la fin de l’année, et possiblement bien moins.

---

#### Jasons météo

[jlliagre](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/1109), toujours rempli d’ingéniosité, a réussi à dénicher un témoignage frappant avec les températures, qui varient entre les froids hivernaux en degrés négatifs et les chaleurs estivales en degrés positifs :

> « Ç’a démarré le 2 février, le jour de la foire du Petit-Madieu. Le vent du nord a commencé à souffler pendant plusieurs jours. C'était encore pire qu’aujourd'hui. Les températures étaient ***descendues à moins 20 degrés, voire plus***. »
>   <sub>—[Source](http://www.charentelibre.fr/2012/02/11/hiver-1956-fevrier-2012-les-memoires-a-vif,1079335.php)</sub>

Plus de -20, ça va habituellement vers -19 et les autres valeurs moins négatives que -20, donc généralement vers 0 et l’ensemble des températures positives, ce qui semble incompatible avec l’idée qui semble ici avancée que le froid était si intense que -20 est une estimation prudente du froid qui s’abattit sur la région.

Il convient alors de comprendre que ce qui augmentait était la DESCENTE DE LA TEMPÉRATURE : les thermomètres avaient descendu jusqu’à moins 20, et peut-être encore PLUS BAS que ça.

Je constate avec cet exemple que le contexte nous informe si bien de ce qu’il faut comprendre que même en substituant ***moins*** à ***plus***, nous avons encore la même affirmation :

> « Ç’a démarré le 2 février, le jour de la foire du Petit-Madieu. Le vent du nord a commencé à souffler pendant plusieurs jours. C'était encore pire qu’aujourd'hui. Les températures étaient descendues à moins 20 degrés, voire ***moins***. »

Peut-être que cette version plairaît davantage aux gens portés aux mathématiques, et moins à ceux que les nombres embêtent et qui ont plus tendance à juger de la grandeur d’un nombre en évaluant sa valeur absolue. On ne saurait contenter tout le monde.

---

#### Conclusion

Je dois admettre ne pas avoir de conclusion à offrir. Je suis confus, tiraillé par les justes arguments de gens qui ne voient rien de mal à la tournure, au point qu’ils ne discutent même pas de la possibilité qu’elle puisse être étrange, et ma perception initiale, qui me semble elle aussi recevable.

Comment: *Le vent du nord a commencé à souffler pendant plusieurs jours. C'était encore pire qu'aujourd'hui. Les températures étaient descendues à moins 20 degrés, voire plus.* http://www.charentelibre.fr/2012/02/11/hiver-1956-fevrier-2012-les-memoires-a-vif,1079335.php

Comment: @jlliagre Très belle trouvaille! Merci de l’avoir soumise, même si ma confusion plonge vers des valeurs abyssales (sur une échelle logarithmique inversée).